# Update private static final int in base class for unittest

Tags: java, unit-testing, reflection

I try to change the int value of a **private static final int** for unittesting.
I looked at http://zarnekow.blogspot.de/2013/01/java-hacks-changing-final-fields.html
and http://java-performance.info/updating-final-and-static-final-fields/ and other stackoverflow examples like: [changing final variables through reflection, why difference between static and non-static final variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18124505/changing-final-variables-through-reflection-why-difference-between-static-and-n)

30 Seconds is a default timer. i want to set it with setOverReflectionMax_SECONDS(3); to 3 seconds.
**But it does not work, any hints ?**

My baseclass with

```
public class BaseClass {

    private static final int MAX_SECONDS = 30;

}
```

and other class

```
public final class MyClass extends BaseClass {

    public static List<Field> getFields(final Class<?> clazz){
        final List<Field> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.addAll(Arrays.asList(clazz.getDeclaredFields()));

        if(clazz.getSuperclass() != null){
            list.addAll(getFields(clazz.getSuperclass()));
        }
        return list;
    }

    public static void setOverReflectionMax_SECONDS(final int newValue) {

        final List<Field> fields = getFields(MyClass.class);
        for (final Field field : fields) {
            if (field.getName().equals("MAX_SECONDS")) {

                field.setAccessible(true);   //EDIT 4 

                Field modifiersField;
                try {
                    modifiersField = Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers");
                    modifiersField.setAccessible(true);
                    modifiersField.setInt(field, field.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);
                    field.set(null, newValue);
                } catch (final Exception e2) {
                    e2.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
    }

}
```

Edit1: wrong classname

Edit2: I cant change BaseClass (got only the .class file)

Edit3: new Exception

```
Class MyClass can not access a member of class BaseClass with modifiers "private static"
```

Edit4 : see code , fixes the exception, but it does not change the int

Comment: Why don't you just temporarily modify the variable by hand and rerun your unit test?  This seems like a lot of work to simply change a final variable for testing.

Comment: i only have the .class, not .java so i cant change it

Comment: So if you can't change it, why would you want to change it for unit testing?

Comment: Secondly, I'm assuming you get an exception from this?  What does that look like?

Comment: @tier1 He doesn't get an exception; the change simply makes no effect due to inlining of constants.

Comment: I try to run some negative tests. the MAX_SECONDS is a timeout, so each negative test, will take 30 seconds. Basically i try to find something that isnt there and i dont need to wait the whole 30 seconds

Comment: Sorry my bad, i forgot the exception, i am looking to long on the output

Comment: i forgot field.setAccessible(true); but now i got no exception and it does not change the value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be possible even using reflection, because the value of the field may be inlined by the compiler (I believe the compiler is free to choose whether it does this or not). In that case, a copy of the value is hardcoded where it is actually used, and can be changed only by manipulating the byte code.

This is explained in more detail in this question: [Change private static final field using Java reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3301635/change-private-static-final-field-using-java-reflection).

**tl,dr:** There is no way to reliably change a `static final` field using reflection. Your options are:

- manipulate the byte code (a rather desperate option)
- find another solution (subclass, wrapper, proxy...)
- (bug the author to) change the source code, to make the value settable/configurable

Comment: thanks! i will wait until tomorrow if someone got it working, if not i will accept your answer